# EF5 and Stored Procedure - FunctionImport Not found in Container

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have been dealing with this for a couple weeks now, and figured it was time to bring someone  else in. I have been to many sites trying to solve this, but I'll start from the beginning.

This is my first project in mvc and ef, so I have relied on a lot of tutorials.
I started with this one...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

Everything else I find on the web pretty much just shows me the same things, so I figured this was pretty simple.

The stored procedure in question is pretty simple, it just returns a string from a table.

```
SELECT TOP 1 ConnectionString 
FROM tConfig 
WHERE Active = 1
```

I generated an edmx file, like in the article above, and it generated the following code in a context file. I have tried this both with, and without the EntityContainerName next to the procedure.

```
    public virtual ObjectResult<string> psMasterDataSource()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("CentralApp.psMasterDataSource");
    }
```

Where I am using it is also pretty simple.

```
    public string GetMasterDSConn() {
        var context = new CentralApp();
        var conn = context.psMasterDataSource().SingleOrDefault();
        return conn;
    }
```

But when I run it, I get the following error.

> *The FunctionImport 'psMasterDataSource' could not be found in the container 'CentralApp'.*

I saw someone on another site talked about editing the XML, but I couldn't find anything helpful on what to edit. So I am hoping I am missing something simple there.

I appreciate any help on this. I am ready to get this app tested, but this is holding me back.

Comment: Have you added the function import in the designer? Do you see the function in model browser?

Comment: It is there under the Function Imports, when I added the stored proc, following the method from my link, it added it for me. I have a structure like this in model browser   CentralApp.edmx > CentralAppModel > Function Imports > psMasterDataSource

Comment: @mmeasor I'm having the same issue as you are...I've added it to the model, added the Import Function, assigned the type, it compiles, but when I run it, I get the same error on the same line.  It's almost as if EF can't find it or never attaches that SP to the model.  Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: good to know I am not alone, but honestly, i gave up and went back to creating my connection with sqlclient. This was the only thing left on the entire project.

it would still be nice to find a solution, since I feel bad abuot what I did.